# Probability bound on Maxima under random sampling

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, approximation, tail-bound

I have a set $S$ = {$e_1,e_2,..e_{400}$} of 400 elements and a non-linear function $f:2^{(S)}\to[0,1]$ that takes a subset of $S$ and returns a real number in $[0,1]$. I want to compute the subset for which $f$ attains the highest value.

Computing $f$ for a given input takes quite a bit of time (~1 hour) and it's not practically feasible to use any optimization algorithm on $f$. I'm trying to sample $n$ points randomly and compute $f(.)$ on those points.

Let $\alpha$ be the maximum among the observed values. Based on the observed mean and variance, Can I make a claim of some sort like: $P(f(S) \ge \alpha) \le \beta$ with a margin of error $e$. In that case how many samples do I need to make a statistical significant claim?

Comment: What kind of function is $f$?  How does it react to the inclusion or exclusion of a single element from a subset?

Comment: There is no restriction on how f should react to inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: If $f$ is totally arbitrary than I would have thought you are simply trying to find the largest value of $2^{400}$ possibilities and there are no shortcuts except knowing that none exceed $1$

Comment: Can you give some information about $f$? without that, the only thing you can do is some simulation